# Overlap a specific element in an Item of Itemscontrol

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am Developing a Calendar app similar to the one in Windows 10.

I have defined Each day (24 hours) as an item for itemtemplate.

Calendar App in Win 10 can have multiple all day events that span through one ore more days.

[image: All day Event that spans for two days in win 10 calendar app]

I have defined a Button for displaying all day event ("Some Very Big Content")

[image: As Defined by me]

Now, If the Full day event spans through more than one day, I want to span that button alone to next item. without spanning the whole day item.

The below is the Structure of my Day Item Control:

[image: As Defined by me]

How can it be achieved in UWP?

Code I have tried:

```
 <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="MyListView" Loaded="MyListView_Loaded"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
        <ItemsControl   ItemsSource="{x:Bind Days}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DayDataTemplate}"  
           Margin="-10,0,0,0"         >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                   <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>


            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ListView>
```

*Days in ItemSource consists of 2 Grids

Grid 1 has a Textblock, Button and a textblock stacked vertically.

And its Structure:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1"  >
                <StackPanel Name="AllDayButtonStackPanel" 

                            Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.5">
                    <ToggleButton Name="AllDayToggleButton"
                                  Content="Some veryyy Bigggggggggg Contennnnnnttttt                                            sdgsdgsdgsdfgsdfgsdfn"
                                  VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpan="2"                                       
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Background="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                                  Canvas.ZIndex="99">                            
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Date}" FontSize="25" Margin="50,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
```

I just wanted to expand the AllDayToggleButton till next day or more!

Comment: please add the code snippet you have tried till now.

Comment: Have Edited the Post..and too chk the image in first answer. (Am not allowed to post more than 2 links in question )

Comment: I have edited your question by even adding the 3rd image. You can accept my edit and delete the thing you have posted in the answer section. Because, answer section is meant only for answers.